# Java GuardTypes analogy for OCaml

Tags: ocaml

How do you do, Stackoverflow!

In Java practice there are some issues concerning partially defined functions. Sometimes it's convinient to separate an error handling from the calculation itself. We may utilize an approach called "Guard types" or "Guard decorators".
Consider the simple synthetic example: to guard the null reference. This can be done with the aid of the next class

```
public class NonNull<T> {
    public take() {
        return null != this.ref ? this.ref : throw new ExcptionOfMine("message");
    }

    public NotNull(T ref_) {
        this.ref     = ref_;
    }

    private T ref;       
}
```

**The question is**:
Is there a way to implement the same "Guard type" in OCaml without touching its object model? I believe for the OCaml as the functional programming language to  possess enough abstraction methods without objec-oriented technics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an abstract type to get the same effect. OCaml has no problem with null pointers. So say instead you want to represent a nonempty list in the same way as above. I.e., you want to be able to create values that are empty, but only complain when the person tries to access the value.

```
module G :
sig type 'a t 
    val make : 'a list -> 'a t 
    val take : 'a t -> 'a list 
end =
struct
    type 'a t = 'a list
    let make x = x
    let take x = if x = [] then raise (Invalid_argument "take") else x
end
```

Here's how it looks when you use the module:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# #use "m.ml";;
module G :
  sig type 'a t val make : 'a list -> 'a t val take : 'a t -> 'a list end
# let x = G.make [4];;
val x : int G.t = <abstr>
# G.take x;;
- : int list = [4]
# let y = G.make [];;
val y : '_a G.t = <abstr>
# G.take y;;
Exception: Invalid_argument "take".
```

Comment: It appears to be the very answer I have looked for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's a concept of Optional types, on which you can effectively pattern match. Example:

```
let optional = Some 20
let value = 
  match optional with
  | Some v -> v
  | None -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple closures

```
let guard_list v =
  fun () ->
    if v = [] then failwith "Empty list"
    else v

let () =
  let a = guard_list [1;2;3] in
  let b = guard_list [] in
  print_int (List.length (a ()));  (* prints 3 *)
  print_int (List.length (b ()))   (* throws Failure "Empty list" *)
```

or lazy values

```
let guard_string v = lazy begin
  if v = "" then failwith "Empty string"
  else v
end

let () =
  let a = guard_string "Foo" in
  let b = guard_string "" in
  print_endline (Lazy.force a);  (* prints "Foo" *)
  print_endline (Lazy.force b)   (* throws Failure "Empty string" *)
```

Comment: I've considered such an approach.
Yet, I want to declare a type to guard the function parameters, not only lazy avaluate.

Comment: With abstract type one can define a function like this
`let guarded_head g_lst = head (G.take g_lst);;` It's typed as `'a G.t -> 'a`
Now I don't bother with empty lists inside `guarded_head`. `G.take` is responsible for error handling. For instance, one can declare G.take to return some _default value_ specified in `G.make`, instead of just immediate fail.

It you have another idea in mind, then you could be kind to share it with us.